# On meta: multiple answers with different opinions?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, meta

I have a few questions (OK a lot) of questions on meta. On [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15678/is-it-ok-to-comment-and-see-if-it-works-before-answer) question ([Is it ok to comment and see if it works before answer?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15678/is-it-ok-to-comment-and-see-if-it-works-before-answer)) I have different answers with different opinions. Is it ok to not accept an answer, even though they all answer my question?

Comment: Is it OK not to pay developers for writing two games which both are awesome ? Is it OK not to pay a mechanics who both fixed your car, just in a different way ?

Comment: No, but you can't pay them both here on AskUbuntu. You can't accept multiple answers. I have up voted all of them.

Comment: Then let the conscience be your guide, and choose the answer which was better . Your post actually has been asked before, see this : http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14069/295286

Comment: FYI On meta you are not "paying" anyone, no rep or anything is given (some badges eventually), you should pick the one that is the answer you were looking for and you agree with or the one with the most detail or what ever criteria you like. Think of accepting on meta more like saying "The subject can be closed, I am satisfied" than "this is right". It can be hard to choose but you should. No one will be offended if you don't pick there answer.

Comment: @Serg setting aside the obvious issues about considering accepting an answer as "payment", this question is about *meta* where payment is even more meaningless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it should be clear by now that you should *always* accept *my* answers.

Seriously, Meta is mostly about discussion. That means it is to find, if possible, some kind of consensus, within the scope of the site, *and* to find out which opinion(s) possibly exist in the community.

Therefore downvotes, upvotes and acceptance or not, those are almost by definition done *subjectively*. That means you can accept what describes how you *think* it should be, or answers your question the way you like (most).

Comment: +1 Great answer. But I won't listen to that - always accept my answers.